# How to param min CPU speed on VM on the VMWARE?

Tags: optimization, virtual-machine, vmware

vmware: 7.0u2

I have created 10 VM's with 6 CPU  per host with 8 GB of RAM, putted in vmx file:

```
- sched.cpu.latencySensitivity = "medium"
- sched.cpu.units = "mhz"
- sched.cpu.min = "999"
```

But when I see in "UI/Navigator/Hosts" the barprogress only show "2 Ghz" of usage when the "Memory" barprogress a 50% of usage.

If I go to "UI/Navigator/Virtual Machines" I can see VM's only work with 18 Mhz or 141 Mhz!

[1] Why my VM's don't work with the min: 999 Mhz?

[2] How I can force the VM's work always with "1 Ghz" min????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "UI/Navigator/Virtual Machines" Show values several values but is not the reference clock speed in to VM.

When I go in to VM (auth) and I check the clock speed in "Task Manager/Performance" in Windows I see the correct value.

In Linux I checked with "lscpu" command and I see the correct value.

Cordially.